# Messages are not getting consumed from solace queue

Tags: java, spring-integration, solace-mq

I am using spring integration `int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter` to consume message from solace queue.

I see below mentioned error in server logs

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer- Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: Error comitting - transaction rolled back (Transaction '12427' unexpectedly rolled back during commit attempt. (((Client name: xxxx.yyyy.com/7034/#0002000a   Local addr: 123123  Remote addr: aaa.bbb.com:12345) - )  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Message Consume Failure [Subcode:48]))
```

JMS configuration is as mentioned below

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="IdMessageDrivenChannelAdapter" send-timeout="5000"
        max-messages-per-task="-1"
        idle-task-execution-limit="100"
        max-concurrent-consumers="2"
        connection-factory="appCachedConnectionFactory" destination="appInQueue"
        channel="reqChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"
        acknowledge="transacted" />
```

Any pointers to solve this error will be really helpful.

Comment: can you post configuration of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`?

Comment: The `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` creates one internally. Can't that `48` subcode be one of this: http://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/1dd5e649-a3ad-e357-604c-c56486a6db94.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a failure to consume a message during a transaction. The cause of the error could be a number of different issues, such as the message was deleted/expired, or queue not found or shutdown.

You can analyze the rest of the API logs or the event logs on the Solace router to find out why the message could not be consumed.

The subcode documentation that you linked in the comments refers to the Solace .NET API. To see a list of errors and their subcodes and explanations for JCSMP errors, please see the documentation here:
http://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/java/constant-values.html